# Rails: Code optimization/restructuring requested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, refactoring, rails-activerecord

I have the following code snippet that works perfectly and as intended:

```rb
    # Prepares the object design categories and connects them via bit mapping with the objects.design_category_flag
    def prepare_bit_flag_positions
      # Updates the bit_flag_position and the corresponding data in the object table with one transaction
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        # Sets the bit flag for object design category
        ObjectDesignCategory.where('0 = (@rownum:=0)').update_all('bit_flag_position = 1 << (@rownum := 1 + @rownum)')

        # Resets the object design category flag
        Object.update_all(design_category_flag: 0)
        # Sets the new object design category bit flag
        object_group_relation = Object.joins(:object_design_categories).select('BIT_OR(bit_flag_position) AS flag, objects.id AS object_id').group(:id)
        join_str = "JOIN (#{object_group_relation.to_sql}) sub ON sub.object_id = objects.id"
        Object.joins(join_str).update_all('design_category_flag = sub.flag')
      end
```

But in my opinion it is quite difficult to read. So I tried to rewrite this code without raw SQL. What I created was this:

```rb
  def prepare_bit_flag_positions
      # Updates the bit_flag_position and the corresponding data in the object table with via transaction
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        # Sets the bit flag for the object color group
        ObjectColorGroup.find_each.with_index do |group, index|
          group.update(bit_flag_position: 1 << index)
        end

        # Resets the object color group flag
        Object.update_all(color_group_flag: 0)
        # Sets the new object color group bit flag
        Object.find_each do |object|
          object.update(color_group_flag: object.object_color_groups.sum(:bit_flag_position))
        end
      end
    end
```

This also works fine, but when I run a benchmark for about 2000+ records, the second option is about a factor of 65 slower than the first. So my question is:

Does anyone have an idea how to redesign this code so that it doesn't require raw SQL and is still fast?

Comment: The problem with this method isn't that its hard to read. It's that its doing 3 different things.

Comment: Also naming your model `Object` is a very very bad idea as it clashes with the most import core class in Ruby (or maybe this is just a bad substitution for the sake of the example?).

Comment: Dont worry, the naming ```Object````was just for stackoverflow. The "real" models naming is different.

Comment: `Object.find_each do |object| `-- rehydrates each object making separate SQL calls.  This is never going to be faster than running update_all.

Comment: @dbugger kind of - `find_each` will load a batch of 1000 rows which are then hydrated and passed to the block - but each row will result in a separate UPDATE query.

Comment: @max - yes, but the point is -- creating objects is not as efficient as updating the database directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 sources of slowing:

1. N+1 problem
2. Instantiating objects
3. Calls to DB

This code has the N+1 Problem. I think this may be the major cause of the slowing.

```
Object.find_each do |object|
  object.update(color_group_flag: object.object_color_groups.sum(:bit_flag_position))
end
```

Change to

```
Object.includes(:object_color_groups).find_each do |object|
  ...
end
```

You can also use `Object#update` class method on this code (see below).

I don't think you can get around #2 without using raw SQL. But, you will need many objects (10K or 100K or more) to see a big difference.

To limit the calls to the DB, you can use `Object#update` class method to update many at once.

```
ObjectColorGroup.find_each.with_index do |group, index|
  group.update(bit_flag_position: 1 << index)
end
```

to

```
color_groups = ObjectColorGroup.with_index.map do |group, index|
  [group.id, { bit_flag_position: group.bit_flag_position: 1 << index }]
end.to_h
ObjectColorGroup.update(color_groups.keys, color_groups.values)
```

The following is a single query, so no need to change.

```
Object.update_all(color_group_flag: 0)
```

Reference:

1. [ActiveRecord#update class method API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-update)
2. [ActiveRecord#update class method blog post](https://prabinpoudel.com.np/notes/update-multiple-records-at-once-in-rails/)
3. [Rails Eager Loading](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#includes)